# How to call jQuery in PHP echo?

Tags: php, jquery, date, datepicker, echo

I have a php web form code with different fields. One filed is name with Date and second is title. I use jQuery datepicker in my form and display current date with calendar in Date input field. In title field I also display current date with php function. Now I want that when I change date in Date Field then it chand automatically  in title filed. So question is that can I call jQuery function again? And how can I call it?

Here is my code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
            });   
  </script>
</head>
<body>

 <form action="form.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

   <table width="547" class="tblbdr" >
    <tr>
        <td height="23"  colspan="6" class="head"><p>  Morning Breifing</p></td>
</tr>
 <tr> <td height="10"></td></tr>
<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Date:</b> </td> <td><input type="text" id="mydate" style="width:200px"> </td></tr>
<tr>

<tr><td class="celltext"><b>Title: </b><br> </td> 
<td class="celltext" style="width:200px"><b> MB | Falcons | <?php echo date("d-M-Y");?></b> </td>
</tr>
<td class="celltext"><b>Upload File:</b></td>
    <td colspan="4" bordercolorlight="#006666">  <input type="file" name="files[]"  multiple style="width:300px"/> </td></tr>
    <td> </td> <td> </td>
    <td width="151">
      <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
   </td>
    <tr>
    <td height="75">
    </td>
    <td width="290">

   </td> </tr>
   </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the output of my code

[image: date]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `onSelect` event to change date.

First i do html changes

```
<td class="celltext" style="width:200px"><b> MB | Falcons |<span id="dt_title"> <?php echo date("d-M-Y");?></span></b> </td> </tr>
```

Now lets use `onSelect` event

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y",
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#dt_title").html(dateText);
        }
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>
```

You can check documentation [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect)

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#mydate").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
  }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
        });   
</script>
```

with this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mydate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
    }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
});   
</script>
```

Example of the page:

```
<?php $myCurrentDate = '2015-06-25'; ?>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    <?php echo '
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#mydate").datepicker({
          dateFormat: "dd-M-y"
        }).datepicker("setDate", new Date());
      }); 
    '; ?>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <?php echo '<input type="text" id="mydate" style="width:200px" value="'.$myCurrentDate.'">'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can u tell me then how i can call it with php echo?

Comment: Javascript runs after php creates page and client get it in his browser. You need to understand what "finish" page code you need and than create it with your PHP. This code will run AFTER php ends. I don't know what code do you want to get at the end, but you need: `echo '<input id="mydate">';` and `echo '<script>..</script>';` for example.

Comment: Actually i want to call jquery in                                                                               <td class="celltext" style="width:200px"><b> MB | Falcons | <?php echo date("d-M-Y");?></b> </td>
</tr>

Comment: What is not working? Check my code in answer. <?php echo date("d-M-Y");?> print just `TEXT`, you need `ELEMENT` to work with JS. Create **working** HTML with JS and than replace some places with PHP.

Comment: when i change my code <?php echo date("d-M-Y");?>    with echo '<input id="mydate">'; and echo '<script>..</script>'; it display nothing

Comment: Sir i want to call jquery two times one in date field and second in title field. And i want when i change date in date field then it will be change automatically in title field

Comment: My code in answer works fine and display input with datepicker. It has no visuality because of I don't include CSS files, but JS and calendar are working. Check your code, you doing something wrong.

Comment: About title - you need to create only JS script for this. PHP doesn't help you. When page in client browser, PHP already finished his work.